# Can not pass metadata with metamask deeplink

Tags: metadata, solidity, deep-linking, transfer, metamask

This is the deep-link:

ethereum:0xBaa11D872cfD22c4D9525E1011af790bB56d656E@1337?value=1e18&data=somedata

And this is the QR that is generated from the url above

[image]

i am not able to receive the metadata from payment receive event in solidity contract

this is the event log:

```
{
  logIndex: 0,
  transactionIndex: 0,
  transactionHash: '0x8d504a1253f30bbc43c5212434dc7dc52a122afc2d08cf6e2c496e34fb316ecd',
  blockHash: '0xcf91cdab48a97255c52532732fff9091a7ff5f371a6552f94aaac55a95fb42b1',
  blockNumber: 33,
  address: '0xBaa11D872cfD22c4D9525E1011af790bB56d656E',
  type: 'mined',
  id: 'log_8ce94ba5',
  returnValues: Result {
    '0': '0x49372600c1BD394922c0B6463611DeD4CbeDAf45',
    '1': '1000000000000000000',
    '2': null,
    _from: '0x49372600c1BD394922c0B6463611DeD4CbeDAf45',
    _amount: '1000000000000000000',
    data: null
  },
  event: 'MoneyReceivedWithData',
  signature: '0xf7d31a904a564a801af9dfae1796bd5fd339d215fedc9314fbfbcffb5c14f205',
  raw: {
    data: '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000de0b6b3a764000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
    topics: [
      '0xf7d31a904a564a801af9dfae1796bd5fd339d215fedc9314fbfbcffb5c14f205',
      '0x00000000000000000000000049372600c1bd394922c0b6463611ded4cbedaf45'
    ]
  }
```

this is the solidity functions:

Event:

```
 event MoneyReceived(address indexed _from, uint256 _amount);
```

Fallback function:

```
 fallback() external payable {
     emit MoneyReceived(msg.sender, msg.value);
 }
```

and as you can see the "data" field in the "returnValues" field is null.

Please help. I found no way to pass a metadata to transaction via mobile metamask QR scan transfer (same as deep-link). I need to understand how to build a proper deep-link url to pass the necessary data to my solidity event-emiter or is it a way to pass a metadata as a parameter through deep-link.

Comment: Can you share the Solidity code of the event definition and the code that emits the event? ... Generally speaking, event data is a different thing from transaction data field, but it's possible to pass the transaction data field to event data.

Comment: These are the things:

Event:
    event MoneyReceived(address indexed _from, uint256 _amount);

Emitter function:
   receive() external payable  {
        emit MoneyReceived(msg.sender, msg.value);
    }